# A regex to match a filename that DOESN'T have an extension

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I'm looking for a regex that will only match when there is NO extension in a file name.

test.doc = no match
testaaa = match

I can posititely find the '.' with /. but how can I negate this? I tried using (?!.) but I get a match on every character of the file name.

Thanks

Comment: Did you already try the `end`-Anchor `$`? `/^[^.]+$/` could help

Comment: There is the "doesn't match" operator, in most languages it's like `something !~ /.../`

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks a lot!

Comment: So, your question is just about how to match anything but dot chars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd check that the file doesn't have any dots with `^[^.]*$`:

```js
var patt = new RegExp("^[^.]*$");

console.log(patt.test('test.doc'));
console.log(patt.test('testaaa'));
```